# Accessing USB webcam via Cortex-M3

Tags: c++, c, embedded, usb, stm32

Afternoon all,

A am wondering if it is at all possible to hijack the video stream of a USB webcam via a microcontroller (STM32F103, Cortex M3, 73MHz) to add a HUD to the device. Then re-package the stream into the same USB endpoint plus a control endpoint?

I can not find any information what so ever on interfacing with a webcam via a micro, but I have found projects that use a parallel interfaced image sensor.

Comment: You meant 72 MHz, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with that chip, which has only a full-speed USB device interface.

You need

- a USB host port
- which supports high-speed
- and a faster processor to deal with that much data

Comment: Hmm, how much MHz would be needed do you think?

Comment: @uMinded: For an ARM, probably 800 MHz or so.  A DSP chip could probably get away with in the range of 300 MHz, as it's optimized for handling streaming data like that.  Just do some quick math, a 640x480x30fps stream is over 9 million pixels per second.  1024x768x30fps is almost 25 million pixels per second.

Comment: Standard webcams have on board micros to collect the data stream and package it for usb delivery, even if it was just puking the data out in isosynchronous mode it would need >25MHz yet every webcam I took apart had no crystals even.

Comment: @uMinded: Behold the wonder of the PLL, which performs clock frequency multiplication.  Also note that the video signal carries a clock signal which is suitable for feeding a PLL, no dedicated crystal is needed.

Comment: Agree with DSP suggestion. TI has quite some ARM/DSP packages.

Comment: I think I might rework my idea and find a way to hijack the pins of the CCD and replace the drive chip as it requires a lot less cycles to package the stream to USB than it does to depackage, add and repackage.

Thanks for the info all!

Comment: @uMinded: That's not a bad idea.  You might first see whether you can figure out what chip it is, it might be reprogrammable.